# How do i enter the current date into the database automatically?

Tags: sql

I have created a database table named bill where the fields are name, email, phone number, billed amount, transaction_date

Now I'm entering the details manually using the insert command. Now what I want is... The transaction date should be automatically set according to the system date. Please let me know if there is a solution using which I don't need to manually enter the current date dry time I add a transaction record.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: Use a default constraint - For SQL Server here is the syntax - ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Table1Column1 DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR Column1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NOW()`  is the date function that will work for you in SQL.`

> `Insert into yourtable values('name',xyz@abc.com','985954',600,NOW());`

`
Also see

> GETDATE()

Comment: And how would that work for Oracle? Or DB2? Or Firebird?